# Possibly unhandled rejection when try to dismiss a modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a cancel button on my modal and has an on-click function that calls:

```
onCancelClick: function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss()
}
```

its work but make this error:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: `undefined`

or when click on <kbd>esc</kbd> key:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: escape key press

I know I can use below code in my config and turn these type of errors off:

```
app.config(function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
});
```

but i want to solve it.
Do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid a `possibly unhandled rejection` message, simply handle the rejection:

```
var modalPromise = $uibModal.open(options).result;

modalPromise
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log("Modal closed with result", result);
}).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("Modal dismissed with reason", reason);
});
```

The `$uibModal.open` method returns an object of which the `result` property is a promise that settles either as fulfilled with the `result` argument of the `.close` operation, or as rejected with the `reason` argument of the `.dismiss` operation.

For more information, see [UI-Bootstrap Directive API Reference - uib.bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal)

Comment: I do like this because I don't want to do anything after dismiss modal:
`var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  //options
});
modalInstance.result.then(angular.noop, angular.noop);
`

Comment: If this answers your question, mark it accepted so that others will know the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$uibModalInstance.close(false)` instead of  `$uibModalInstance.dismiss()` will solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to pass any reason, you can use `$uibModalInstance.close()`. You can have catch block like:

```
try{    
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
} catch (err){
//Check what error you are getting.
}
```

Could be the error is just for `reason` parameter, which is expected in `dismiss` function, though I am not sure about that.

Comment: it works but makes refresh page. I want to dismiss without refresh.